# Why are PHPs "memory_limit" and "max_execution_time" limitations not met when using HTTP Accept-Ranges for serving large files?

Tags: php, apache, http, resources

The following script is used to (evaluate) sending large video files to the client. It is using http headers `Accept-Ranges` in behind. Even when dealing with large files (> 2 GB), no PHP limitations are met (for testing, i've set small values like memory_limit=16MB and max_execution_time=30).

I would like to "understand" the context in behind, as chrome only shows one (partial) request, increasing "time" and "size" every some seconds, although there are no additional requests shown in apache logfile.

```
$file = './videos/' . basename($_GET['video']);

if(!file_exists($file)) return; 

$fp = @fopen($file, 'rb');      
$size   = filesize($file); // File size 
$length = $size;           // Content length
$start  = 0;               // Start byte
$end    = $size - 1;       // End byte  

header('Content-type: video/mp4');
header("Accept-Ranges: 0-$length");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes"); 

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    $c_start = $start;              
    $c_end   = $end;                
    list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
    if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;      
    }              
    if ($range == '-') {            
        $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
    }else{         
        $range  = explode('-', $range); 
        $c_start = $range[0];           
        $c_end   = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $size;
    }
    $c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;
    if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size) { 
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;      
    }
    $start  = $c_start;             
    $end    = $c_end;               
    $length = $end - $start + 1;    
    fseek($fp, $start);             
    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
}   
               
header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
header("Content-Length: ".$length);

$buffer = 1024 * 8;
while(!feof($fp) && ($p = ftell($fp)) <= $end) { 
    if ($p + $buffer > $end) {      
        $buffer = $end - $p + 1;        
    }              
    set_time_limit(0);              
    echo fread($fp, $buffer);       
    ob_flush();    
}
fclose($fp);       
exit();
```

Comment: As to memory, the bottom `while` loop is reading the file in 8KB chunks and echoing them directly to the client, so it is very low from a memory standpoint. If it was concatenating that into a string that's where the server's memory limit would kick in. As to additional requests, to the best on my knowledge, browsers will not create an additional request to the server, even if a range is advertised, except for the case of resuming downloads (or if someone wrote some JS to do that). For timeout, without testing, I would expect the 30 second limit to abort the script, does it?

Comment: Thx for your explanations! The timeout doesn’t abort the script - what I don‘t understand. I will test this again later. Perhaps with a 2GB file the abort is visible to the browser very later than 30 seconds, because the timeout affects the proccesed bytes serverside only, not the duration of the displayed video clientside?

Comment: Regarding the timeout, i've overseen that there is a set_time_limit(0) at the last lines... But event when removing it and setting max_execution_time to 1 i cannot produce a timeout. Now i suppose that the webserver (apache) just logs ONE request for all range requests!?

Comment: I would be surprised if Apache logged just a single request, very surprised. A request for more content is still a valid request so it should be logged. Try throwing some `die`s into the range code to see if it actually hits in the first place. What are you using to invoke the range request in the first place? Also, you can move `set_time_limit` out of the loop, you only need to call that once.

Comment: Independent from starting the first request from within a html 5 video object "src" or calling the script directly, there a 1 - 3 partial requests done first (each about 1 - 5 MB), after that an additional partial request is done which fetches the remaining ~ 3 GB. This 4 requests are shown in apache logfile + chrome developer tools. But because of the data size of the last request, shouldn't it break any time limit? It doesn't, even if `set_time_limit` is removed. I don't understand this! Also, i do not understand why there are 1 - 4 "small" requests and an additional "huge" request?

Comment: In the 30 second window, how much of that 3GB is transferred?

Comment: At 31.26s there are 29.5 MB transferred. And there is no additional request done after reaching 30 seconds... Now on 120s it is still the same request, but 128 MB transferred. Although max_execution_time is set to 30s. There is some magic in behind ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out some more details by requesting the script by commandline using `curl` without any range headers while having `max_execution_time=1` and serving a 2.893 GB file.

On the same machine (abort at 7 seconds and 678 MB):

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed  
23 2893M   23  678M    0     0  92.5M      0  0:00:31  0:00:07  0:00:24     0 
curl: (18) transfer closed with 2322893144 bytes remaining to read
```

On a foreign machine with lower bandwith (abort at 49 seconds and 599 MB):

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed  
20 2893M   20  599M    0     0  12.1M      0  0:03:58  0:00:49  0:03:09 10284 
curl: (18) transfer closed with 2404747608 bytes remaining to read
```

Regarding this, a `max_execution_time=30` isn't really "small" in this context as it allows to transfer estimated about 30 * 600 MB (= 18 GB!). The request duration on clientside has absolutely nothing to do with the serverside execution time.

And indeed, there are several partial requests done when calling the script from within a html5 video object while having `max_execution_time=1` (on a desktop client with even lower bandwith each request takes about 14 minutes until abort and transfers about 500 MB).

Finally, i was simply confused because there is such a huge difference between clientside request duration and serverside execution time.